# How to crawl a s3 bucket for new files

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to crawl a s3 bucket to make sure if there is any new files or objects added to it or deleted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By usin Java AWS SDK, able to connect to S3 bucket from Java and able to crawl the bucket.

Crawling is nothing but taking the objects in a list and comparing and identifying the new object.

Example can be found in `http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/`

Answer (score 2):

Now you can get a message when there is a change. This was just announced (long overdue):
http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-event-notification/

It is very simple to implement - time to throw out all the ugly cron jobs and list-loops.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The information is something promising. I not only need to know the new file is received but I have to also download only the new file to my local file system, Since these files are used for further processing. Do you have any idea how can this be done in more elegant way

Comment: In the message that you receive now from S3 you have the file name and the hash, so you can compare it to the files on your local file system. If you see from the message that the file is new, download this one new file by using the key (the filename) from the message.